# Execute mysqldump with python and set the password via stdin

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I want to execute a mysqldump in python and provide the password when it is requested from the mysqldump.

Adding the password in the command line is not an option, it must be provided via stdin.

This is what I've done so far:
    command = [
        'mysqldump',
        '-h',   mysqlhost,
        '-P',   mysqlport,
        '-u',   mysqluser,
        '-p',
        mysqldb
    ]

```
mysqlfile = mysqlpath + "/" + mysqldb + ".sql"
with open(mysqlfile, "w+") as file:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=file)
    p.communicate(input=mysqlpass)
    p.wait()
```

But when I execute the code the terminal hangs requesting the password.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want it to prompt the password and wait for user input, or do you try to feed a string from your code as the input?

Comment: I want to feed the string from my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pexpect for that. This is modified code as I had to test it, but you get the idea:

```
import pexpect

command2 = 'mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p xyzzy'

mysqlfile = "/tmp/foo.sql"
with open(mysqlfile, "w+") as file:
    p = pexpect.spawn(command2)
    p.expect("Enter password: ")
    p.sendline("foobar")
    q = p.read()
    p.wait()
    file.write(q)
```

here "foobar" is my database password.

Hannu

Comment: Thank you, but now it hangs on p.read() and if I comment this line it hangs in p.wait() function and never ends.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you have typed exactly what is being prompted, in p.expect()?  If you are missing something or if there is an extra character, it would not match and never pass this.   You can debug this by adding p = pexpect.spawn(command2, logfile=sys.stdout).  You will see on screen what happens, what gets prompted and what gets output.  If your database is huge, p.read() of course takes a huge amount of time. In this case, you might need to handle this in chunks as this now reads the whole dump in memory.

Comment: Hi Hannu, yes it is just a matter of time with logfile I  can see that is exporting the database correctly, but it takes then too mucho time using p.read() and then file.write(). Using the mysqldump command in console takes like 3 or 4 seconds, using pexpect takes more than 30 seconds and the timeout is fired. How can I solve this?

Comment: try adding timeout=None to pexpect.spawn(command2, timeout=None, logfile=sys.stdout). Here is a link to pexpect documentation: http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class

Comment: Well, I've found the solution, with `for chunk in p.read(1024): file.write(chunk)` it works fine and fast, and ends correctly. I don't know why p.read() blocks and never ends.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the accepted answer did not solve the problem. Presumably it is related to the python version I am using, which is 3.5.

The difficulties I had:

1. `p.read()` was blocking the process (I always killed the script at some point)
2. The *chunk*-approach by David Rojo did not block, but `.read(1024)` returned integers, where strings where expected by `file.write(...)`. I assume this is related to differences in the way unicode is handled in Python 2 and 3, since adding the parameter `encoding='utf-8'` to `pexpect.spawn()` gave me the proper results. However, then I had to adapt the writing of the file, s.t. it supports unicode as well.
3. Another problem with the `for chunk in p.read(1024):`-approach is, that I experienced the reading to finish before mysqldump finished writing the dump to stdout. I guess that in this case mysqldump was too slow to deliver. I changed my solution, s.t. it waits for EOF.

Note: I just started learning python a couple of days ago, please correct me if my assumptions or conclusions are wrong or misleading.

### Code example

The script below is my minimal working example for calling mysqldump and providing the password when mysqldump asks for it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pexpect
import io

cmd = 'mysqldump -u MYSQL_USER -p DATABASES(S)'
sqlfile = "/home/user/test-database-dump.sql"
password = 'secret'

with io.open(sqlfile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print('Calling mysqldump...')
    p = pexpect.spawn(cmd,encoding='utf-8')
    p.expect("Enter password: ")

    # Send password to mysqldump
    p.sendline(password)

    # Capture the dump
    print('Reading dump from process and writing it to file...')
    while not p.eof():
        chunk = p.readline()
        file.write(chunk)
    print('Finished.')

    p.close()
    print(p.exitstatus, p.signalstatus)
```

Comment: Or maybe `mysqldump [options] --result-file=dump.sql` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-file-options